# How to Access Serialized data in the Controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

How can I get the serialized data in the Controller?

For example i have this data...

```
var str = $('#edit-form-data').serialize(); //string
```

I pass it inro the function like this...

```
editDosage(urlEdit,str);
```

My function is like this...

```
function editDosage(url,res)
{
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: res,
        success:function(data){},
        error: function(data){}
    });     
}
```

How do I get the input value of the serialized data in the Controller in Laravel?

For example, I have included in the edit-form-data the name of the 'store_id' and I want to access it in the controller. Can I do something like?

```
$store_id = Input::get('store_id');
dd($store_id);
```

Comment: Yes you can do `$store_id = Input::get('store_id');`. What does `dd($store_id)` display?

Answer (score 0):

you may also use,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#edit-form-data').ajaxForm(); 
});
```

checkthis out: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Or check this one:

```
 $(document).ready( function(){

        $(document).on('click','#submitButton', function(){
            var _this = this;


            var request = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: jQuery("#form").serialize(),
                dataType: "json"
            });
            request.done(function( msg ) {

            });
            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ){

            });
        });
    });
```

And in php

```
 try {
     // input code
if($_REQUEST){
                    echo json_encode("success");

                } else {
                    echo json_encode("checkinput");
                }

            }catch (Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                echo json_encode("error");
            }
```

Comment: so what does this one do ? can i do something like that ? 
$store_id = Input::get('store_id');

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few different ways to get the input. 
**From the Request**

If your function has a Request parameter, it you can get the input from it.

```
public function methodA(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->all();
}
```

[You can view the documentation on Requests here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests).

**Input Facade**

Similar to requests you can use the Input Facade to get the inputted data.

```
public function methodB() {
    $data = Input::all();
}
```

[You can view the API docs for the Input Facade here.](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.html)

Answer (score 0):

### Jquery code

```
$.post('/ajax', {'_token': $token,data: $this.serialize()}, function(resp) {

    /*optional stuff to do after success */
});
```

### controller function##

```
public function CreateBill()
{
    parse_str($_POST['data'], $data);

    return $data;
}
```